# Ansible - target only where path is defined

Tags: ansible

Busting my brain here. Got a small issues which i'd like to fix.
My goal is to remove files which are older than 8 days in two different folders. My code:

```
- name: check for files
  find:
    paths: "{{ item }}"
    age: 8d
  with_items:
    - /var/log/glusterfs
    - /var/log/glusterfs/bricks
  register: deleteold

- debug: var=deleteold.results[1].files[0].path

- name: remove files older than 8 days
  file:
    path: "{{ item.files[0].path }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ deleteold.results }}"
  # when: ???
```

In this way, Ansible can 'target' the correct files if they exists.
But if no file exists, it will give an error. Because no variable is defined.

What `when` statement should I use to delete only files which are targeted.

For convience:

Create a file which is old -> touch -d 20161010 test.log
And to debug:

```
- debug: var=deleteold.results[1].files[0].path
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nicer way:

```
- find:
    paths:
      - /var/log/glusterfs
      - /var/log/glusterfs/bricks
    age: 8d
  register: old_files

- file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ old_files.files }}"
```